# Is the system wrong in this multiple choice problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I don't see where I am going wrong. I know fore sure that every answer I checked is true.

Comment: The OP has marked correctly 3 answers, which I would say shows his/her thoughts on the problem. Well, it may be homework which prompts people to close it ... hmm for that matter I never read D carefully, and now that I read it I do not know what it says, what are these $y$ and $v$ appearing there, any quantifiers? Ok, don't do homework problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is $\{0\}$ an orthogonal set, apparently so according to the definition? Similarly, 
$\{0,1\}$ is an orthogonal set (of real numbers, that is in dimension $1$). 
Are they linearly independent: No.

So isn't C also true? I would think it is.

You did not give a definition of an orthogonal matrix, apparently the elements are orthogonal unit vectors according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix), so B would indeed be correct.

Answer (score 1):

An orthogonal set of vectors just means that the vectors are mutually perpendicular. Does this mean you have a full basis set of them?